# How to browse my own source code in QtCreator debugger

Tags: debugging, qt, qt-creator

during debuging with QtCreator I cannot browser my own source code. I build qt sources with the debug option and as you can see the filenames of the qt source code itself are visible and I can browse them with no problem. But somehow the `CONFIG+=debug` has no effect on my build.

**build output:**

```
Running build steps for project tcpconnector...
Starting: "/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.7.4-DEBUG/bin/qmake" /home/user1/server/src-server/server.pro -r -spec linux-g++-64 CONFIG+=debug
The process "/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.7.4-DEBUG/bin/qmake" exited normally.
Starting: "/usr/bin/make" 
...
```

In the screenshot from the QtCreator debugger you can see that my own code Server::deleteDuplicateConnection is grayed out.

[image: Debugger screenshot with grayed out source file]

Comment: Ok, I already thought it will be something silly. I manually checked my .pro file to make shure there is no "release" keyword in a `CONFIG+=` line, executed the `clean` option from the menu, de- and reselected the `debug` option in the build properties and pressed `Ctrl+S` in between to save the project build options. Solved. Maybe this is not happening in the latest QtCtreator anymore? Hopefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like written in the comment. This just seemed to be a *random* phenomenon.